# User space NFS server needed

Tags: linux, nfs

I need to run NFS within an LXC container (meaning I can't use the kernels NFS driver).

Ergo I need a user space NFS server.

- UNFS3 - seems like the obvious choice, but it doesn't compile on Ubuntu 12.04 and has no support
- NFS-GANESHA - another option, but I failed to get it to compile, the list of dependencies seemed to go on indefinitely and then it finally just failed with indecipherable make errors.

Are there any options that are actively maintained and have a user community? Or that just plain work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nfs-ganesha should be fine. There should be EPEL quite soon, but they are RHEL centric. Depending on your needs, there a java based nfs server from dCache project https://github.com/dCache/jpnfs.git. It's dCache specific, but they can serve disk files as well if needed.

Comment: I finally got UNFS3 to compile in the end

Answer (score 0):

other possibilities though are ftp, samba & webdav

http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/
http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/